# window.open is javascript or html?

Tags: javascript, window

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.open('newstudent.php');"/>
```

This code works correctly, without `script` tag, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an element's inline event handler, like `onclick`, `onchange`, `onsubmit`, etc., you do *not* need the `javascript:` prefix - the reason you often see it is because people confuse it with the `href` syntax that I explain below. It doesn't cause an error - I believe it is interpreted as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) - but it is unnecessary.

It doesn't matter whether you want to call a function or run a "simple" JS statement, either way don't include `javascript:` - that is, all three of these are valid:

```
onclick="doSomething('some val');"
onclick="return false;"
onclick="doSomething(); doSomethingElse(); return false;"
```

**If you are using inline event attributes don't use the `javascript:` prefix.**

(I say "*if* you are using inline event attributes" because this practice is really outdated: it is better to assign the event handlers using JS in a script block.)

You only need the `javascript:` prefix when you want to run JavaScript from an `<a>` element's `href` attribute like this:

```
<a href="javascript: someFunc();">Whatever</a>
```

That is because the browser normally expects the `href` to contain a URI, so the `javascript:` prefix tells it to expect JS code instead. However, I don't recommending doing that because the page won't work for people who have JS disabled. Better to include an `href` that directs the user to a page telling them to enable JS, and include an `onclick` to do the JS functionality:

```
<a href="/enableJS.html" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">Whatever</a>
```

That way the link does something useful for users whether they have JS enabled or not. The `return false` at the end of the click handler prevents the default behaviour for a click (which would be to navigate to the specified URL).

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` attribute works more or so like this JavaSript.

```
input.onclick = function() {
    // The code from the value.
};
```

There is no requirement that the `script` element be present to run JavaScript. Some browsers are/were even stupid enough to execute JavaScript via CSS.